# FluentNHibernate configure LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry and Custom Linq STDistance Spatial SQL Server 2008

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I want to create a new Linq custom method with `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`, to use SQL Server 2008 `STDistance` geography function, How can I do:

1) Map my high level method (`Coordinate.DistanceTo(other)` instance method) to be exchanged by `geoPoint.STDistance(otherGeoPoint)` in SQL Server? My attempts are this:

```
public class DistanceMethodGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public DistanceMethodGenerator()
    {
        base.SupportedMethods = new[] { ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<ICoordinate>(coordinate => coordinate.DistanceTo(null)) };
    }
    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {

        //what to do here to tranform: coord.DistanceTo(otherCoord) in sql     //coord.STDistance(otherCoord)?
        return ????
    }
}
public sealed class LinqToSqlGeneratorRegistrypublic : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public LinqToSqlGeneratorRegistrypublic()
    {
        RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<ICoordinate>(coordinate => coordinate.DistanceTo(null)),
                          new DistanceMethodGenerator());
    }
}
```

2) How register that with fluentNHibernate, I cannot found a method like `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<LinqToSqlGeneratorRegistrypublic >()` in FluentNHibernate

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ExposeConfiguration(c =>
{
  c.Properties.Add(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry, typeof(LinqToSqlGeneratorRegistrypublic).AssemblyQualifiedName)
}
```

Comment: this configuration already exists in my code, the point is: how to implement BuildHql method when database function call is like "coord1.STDistance(coord2)" instead "dbo.distanceTo(coord1, coord2)".